# How to simulate pressing save/enter in SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm creating an application to automate some processes. One of them is creating docx file from the dotx template.

Steps are quite easy: app opens MS Word with test.dotx file and SaveAs it to c:\temp as a test.docx. It should be as close to user's actions as possible. When the file is opened (from dotx so it is docx already) all I need is to open SaveAs dialog and push "save" (or just "enter", because focus is set on "save" button).

The problem is how to "hit" the save/enter. I tried SendKeys but I am in ShowDialog() which is waiting for the result and cannot perform SendKeys at the moment. Of course if I press enter from keyboard or cklick on "Save" all works perfectly, but this one "press" I'd like to do from the code. Could you please point me how to solve this (if it is possible at all)? Thank you.

Here is the part of the code I'm strugglig with:

```
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = @"C:\Temp\",
            DefaultExt = "docx",
            FileName = "test"
        };

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            object FileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            doc.SaveAs(ref FileName);
        }
```

Comment: why do you use an savefile dialog and automatically hit enter? Why not just use the normal predefined save function? if you need the user input there is no need for a simulated input. Just for learning purposes, you have to call a Backgroundworker or other Thread with a predefined Timeout or other check if a Window is open and send the keypress to that window

Comment: There are several reasons it has to be this way - this app is connected with alternate data strem, document properties, and software in the backgroud which all together product different result when this process is done "in the user way" and as if it was done progamatically only. I was thinking about multi threads but I'd like to aviod it. I'll check this backgroundworker" - many thanks

Comment: for your bgworker, you can use this article to check for open windows, then you can set focus to that window and send a keypress. https://www.tcx.be/blog/2006/list-open-windows/

Advanced programming could be the MS Automation Framework since all MS Office applications support it

Answer (score 0):

If hit the save/enter is your requirement, the recommendation is use [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) (this Tool can be installed by Visual Studio Installer) to capture both: "the dialog with save button" and "save button" alias/class; then, programming with C# PInvoke (for example, using [FindWindow](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow) and [FindWindowEx](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindowex)) to send/post message to simulate this "save" button.